# Find line by one word in vector

Tags: c++, string, file, vector, find

Trying to find a line by one word in a vector.

**For example:**

*In a file some data,like:*

> ctrl+a move,find
>
> ctrl+c copy,group
>
> ctrl+z take,give

*all letters are small.*

Then I tried to read a file in vector - it's okay

Then the user want to input : move

**I want that if the user input `move`, I find a line in vector,which has the word `move` and do something with this line.(for example: erase)*

But what do I do wrong , because my loop stops on zero and it reads only the first string of a file?

code is below:

```
void HotMap::test(std::string str)
{   
        std::string line;
        std::vector<std::string> vec_keys;
        std::string file_name_keys("read_keys.txt");
        std::ifstream file_keys(file_name_keys, std::ios::in);
        std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter_vec;


        while (std::getline(file_keys, line))
        {
            for (auto & c : line) c = tolower(c);
            vec_keys.push_back(line);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            vec_keys[i].find(str);
            if (vec_keys[i].find(str))
            {
                std::string found_str;
                std::cout << "Found:" << vec_keys[i];
                //Just help to find the line.....
                break;
            }
        }   
}
```

Comment: hint: what is the return type of `vector::find` ?

Comment: @tobi303 Oh, yes, it's index. But can you help to sta on the right way?

Comment: @tobi303 you mean `string::find`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the ref of [`string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/):

> **Return Value**
>
> The position of the first character of the first match. If no matches were found, the function returns `string::npos`.

So, try this instead:

```
if (vec_keys[i].find(str) != std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "Found:" << vec_keys[i];
```

Comment: I agree  with it

Comment: @X21 because it enters the body of the if statement and the `break` gets executed.

Comment: @gsamaras       Thank you so much! Yes, I got all my mistakes! Thank you for helping!!!!!!